# Why is "Für Elise" called "La Lettre à Elise" in French?

Tags: song-title, beethoven

Beethoven's famous "Für Elise" is literally translated as "À Elise" in French, but that's not what was chosen (by whom ?); instead it is customarily translated as "Lettre à Elise" ("Letter for Elise", "Brief für Elise").

Is there any reason why that's so ? "À Elise" doesn't sound any worse to my (french) ear.

Comment: Translations of titles are often either bad or have nothing to do with the original. If you don't like a specific translation you can just use the original (in English the title of this piece is not normally translated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Ludwig Nohl discovered  "Für Elise"  he included the work in his 1867 publication ["New Beethoven Letters" (Neue Briefe Beethovens)](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=0_EoAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA28#v=onepage&q&f=false) (pages 28-33). "Für Elise" merely refers to the letter written to Elise, and is a name applied after Nohl, rather than by Nohl himself. For comparison, other collected [letters of Beethoven](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/13065/13065-h/13065-h.htm) are entitled with the name of the intended recipient.

The French title "Lettre à Elise" ("Letter for Elise", "Brief für Elise") is most likely an association with Nohl's publication owing to the composition being included within the letter.

I have been unable to locate a French translation of "Neue Briefe Beethovens" to verify whether the composition was given this title from a translation of Nohl. The balance of probability is that the title "Lettre à Elise" was applied through common usage and became fixed.

It is unlikely that we will ever know who first gave the work this French title.